# Loop through each Specific files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to iterate over each Excel (XLSX)files containing special character in a folder and copy the data from each file and Append to another file just below The last available row in Another File.

Input Folder Structure:

```
JCB_Infra Pvt Ltd.xlsx
Indiana_Jesx_Infra Pvt Ltd.xlsx
Nvidia_Softwares Ltd.Xlsb
NGX-India_Infra Pvt Ltd.xlsx
Solatire_Infrastructure Pvt Ltd.xlsx
ADX_Infra pvt ltd.csv
```

We only have to iterate over the files with .xlsx extension and Containing "Infra Pvt Ltd", And Append all the Data available without headers to another File.

Code I have been Using:

```
Sub Append_Files():
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim File_path As Variant

stat_val = "Infra Pvt Ltd"
File_path  = Dir("C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\MixedFiles\") 
While File_path <> ""
     set xWB = Workbooks.Open(File_path & "*.xlsx"
     MsgBox xWB
```

Need Help:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Append_Files()
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim File_path As Variant
    Dim stat_val As String
    
    stat_val = "Infra Pvt Ltd"
    File_path = Dir("C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\MixedFiles\*.xlsx")
    
    While File_path <> ""
        If InStr(File_path, stat_val) Then
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(File_path)
            Set Sheet1 = xWb.Sheets(1)
            ' Append data from Sheet1 to another workbook below the last used row
            '...
        End If
        File_path = Dir
    Wend
    ' Copy data from Sheet1 and paste it to the last used row of the destination workbook
    Sheet1.Range("A1:D10").Copy
    DestinationWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, For the Suggestion But Couldn't Enter into the If Condition "If InStr(File_Path, stat_val) Then", It always jumps to the Else Statement. It Seems all the stat_val is connected by _ in the filenames (Might be the reason). Please suggest the possible way.

Comment: Please suggest what needs to be changed?

Comment: Might be case sensitive, try this:
If InStr(Ucase(myCell.Text), Ucase(Text)) > 0 Then